# recursive find for specific text for last n lines

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to find some specific text in recursive way, I have read this very popular answer:

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'pattern'
```

But it doesn't work to me due to I have files HUGE that can takes so long to find in the whole file, so I want just to search in the last N lines to improve the performance and time required to do the action, for instance:

Comment: You can do it something like that, but this variant loses line numbers: `find '/path/to/somewhere/' -type f | xargs tail | grep -ew 'pattern' `

Comment: Can I add to that tail the -n param?

Answer (score 0):

This code will print **all** files, after each filename matched string will be printed. You can play with parameters to make exactly what you want. For example if you move -print to the end, then only matched files will be printed (but after matched strings)

```
find /path/to/somewhere/ -type f -print -exec bash -c "cat -n {} | tail | grep -we pattern" \;
```

Comment: Where can I set the number of lineS?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [GNU's `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), `bash`, and `tail`:

```
my_tail_grep() {
    file="$1"
    pattern="$2" 
    N="${3:-100}"  # Optional -- defaults to 100
    res=$(tail -n "$N" "$file" | grep -we "$pattern")
    [[ -n "$res" ]] && echo -e "${file}\n${res}" || :
}

export -f my_tail_grep # Necessary for parallel 

find /path -type f | parallel my_tail_grep {} "$pattern" 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` command specifying *the last N lines* via `n` argument:

```
n=11
find /path/to/somewhere/ -type f -exec sh -c 'tail -n '$n' {} | grep -wn pattern' \; -print
```

Comment: It seems it almost what I wanted, it is not printing the file where is the text is

Comment: @DanielHernández, you didn't mention that in your question. See my update